# Codificação mysql

Tags: mysql, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8

Eu tenho os dados no banco, no charset utf-8, e quero exportar a listagem em .csv, porém quando dou um select ele me retorna os dados assim por exemplo "AdministraÃ§Ã£o de ImÃ³veis e LocaÃ§Ã£o".
Como faço para ele retornar os dados no select acentuados corretamente?

PS. Estou usando HeidiSQL.

Comment: Tá usando PHP??

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer sua consulta assim:

```
SELECT convert(campo USING latin1) FROM tabela
```

Com mais de 2 campos

```
SELECT convert(campo USING latin1), convert(campo2 USING latin1) FROM tabela
```

`campo` - é a informação que queres listar.